# Trying to connect solar inverter to wifi gateway

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I've a T-Mobile gateway hotspot*  that I've finally gotten to work well by moving it to an upstairs window.

In the old location I had a solar inverter connected via ethernet cable directly to the gateway.
How can I connect the solar inverter to the new location without an ethernet cable?

I've tried a Netgear extender with a ethernet port, but after several hours including time with Netgear support, it still isn't working.

[image: https://tmo.report/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/new_gateway_1.png]
Thanks for any and all help.